# How to make redux store behave as an observable?

Tags: javascript, redux, rxjs

[Here](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/issues/303#issuecomment-125184409), it is recommended to use the following code to make an observable stream from a Redux store instead of subscribing directly to it.

```
function toObservable(store) {
  return {
    subscribe({ onNext }) {
      let dispose = store.subscribe(() => onNext(store.getState()));
      onNext(store.getState());
      return { dispose };
    }
  }
}
```

I can't figure out how this can be integrated into Rx. How something like `Observable.fromReduxStore` can be implemented using this code?.

Comment: use `Rx.Observable.create` to create you new operator and set it on the prototype. i.e. `Rx.Observable.prototype`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For one there is already a library for [this](https://github.com/acdlite/redux-rx), but if you want to roll your own to work with RxJS. (Disclaimer: untested)

```
Rx.Observable.fromReduxStore = function(store) {
  return Observable.create((observer) => {
    let dispose = store.subscribe(() => observer.next(store.getState()));
    observer.next(store.getState());
    return dispose;
  });
};
```

As a special note depending on the version you are using RxJS v4 `Observer` uses `onNext` while v5 it is `next`.